# Unhandled promise rejections after UpdateMany using Mongo in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using following code for storing documents in mongo db

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect(settings.DB_MONGO_CONNECTOR, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err
    this.mongoCollection = db.db(settings.DB_MONGO_TABLE)
        .collection(this.mongoTableName)
})

//......

let arr = []

//......

this.mongoCollection.updateMany(arr, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Document was saved')
}, { upsert: true })
```

After call updateMany I am getting error:

```
(node:8228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: The update operation document must contain at least one atomic operator.
(node:8228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why? Its valid command, or not?

Comment: `.connect()` is async. Looks like you're calling `.updateMany` before the connection has been established.

Comment: Thank you, yes i know, its fixed by callback, this is only example...

Comment: OK, so what do you see if you log out `err` instead of throwing it?

Comment: err is undifined, this error is in core of library

Comment: You need to try catching your promises. This won't be an error in the core, it'll be how you're using it. Difficult to say without seeing your actual code.